# How do I add hours to the result of SQL Server's `GetDate()` function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to add 2 hours to the result of `getdate()` in SQL SERVER.  I know that I can add one day with:

```
select getdate() + 1
```

But how is this done when wanting to add on hours onto `getdate()`?

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this question as "Not Real;" this is exactly what I was looking for and it was very easy to tell what is being "asked here."  Question is not vague, not incomplete, not broad, and was easily answered.

Answer (score 34):

```
select dateadd(hour,2,getdate())
```

Comment: This can be an option but OP did not ask for alternative.

Answer (score 10):

```
Select GETDATE() + (Convert(float,2)/Convert(float,24))
```

OR in other way

```
Select DateAdd(HH,2,Getdate())
```

Comment: The first one is wrong. Beware of truncations in integers. It is not reliable too

Comment: You edited your post. Still method 1 is not relaible. Use method2

Comment: 1) ----> SELECT DATEADD(hour,2,GETDATE())

2) ----> SELECT DATEADD(HH,2, GETDATE())  This two worked for me.

Comment: I'm recording the event the transaction took place and added `(dateadd(hour,2,getdate()))` to the Default Value or Binding property of my table field and it worked just fine.  My users are local but server is in a differnt time zone so I just needed a small tweak to account for that.  If users were global, then this solution would not work for you.